# webdriverIO and saucelab integration not working

Tags: webdriver-io, saucelabs

When I tried connecting webdriverIO with sauce labs, I'm getting error as

I'm using sauce service

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./config/int.wdio.conf.js

Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-08-30T20:11:14.720Z

2020-08-30T20:11:14.768Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2020-08-30T20:11:14.770Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2020-08-30T20:11:14.772Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: ./config/int.wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.414Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.422Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the ./protocol-stub protocol
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /e2e/test/login.int.spec.js
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.704Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.706Z INFO webdriver: [POST] https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.706Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true }
}
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.733Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:891:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/test/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
[0-0] 2020-08-30T20:11:15.733Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "https://ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
    at startWebDriverSession (/test/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:45:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0-0]  Error:  Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "https://ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - /e2e/test/login.int.spec.js
2020-08-30T20:11:15.848Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:  0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:01 

2020-08-30T20:11:15.849Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2020-08-30T20:11:16.102Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2020-08-30T20:11:16.102Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

my wdio.config.js looks like

```
exports.config = {
    runner: 'local',
    user: 'test123',
    key: '65434d10-276f-4305-adb4-93a39848d445',
    region: 'us',
    specs: [
        './e2e/test/*.int.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
        './e2e/test/*.prod.spec.js',
        './e2e/test/*.ie.int.spec.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
    capabilities: [
        {
            maxInstances: 1,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            acceptInsecureCerts: true
        }
    ],
    logLevel: 'info',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: ['sauce'],
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['mochawesome'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    }
}
```

any idea how to fix this...

Comment: Hmm, everything looks good to me. Are you sure the user/key is correct?

Comment: @KevinLamping Thanks. The issue is with using a puppeteer inside the test file. I moved it to onpreare which fixed it

Comment: That makes sense. Puppeteer uses a specific endpoint that wouldn't be available using the Webdriver endpoint that Sauce provides. Glad you were able to figure it out!